# gcc -lnsl error in socket programming on mac os

Tags: c, macos, sockets

I am trying to compile my C socket programming files using gcc with -lnsl option on MAC OS but it gives me this error:

> ld: library not found for -lnsl
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

This is the gcc command:

```
gcc -o server -lnsl server.c
```

I looked all over the internet but I can't find sth relevant to help me. How to install the missing library? Or should I reinstall gcc? Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: The `nsl` library might not exist on all systems. Its functions can be in other libraries.

Comment: Then how can I use socket programming on mac os? What option should I use? I need to make use of                                                           #include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

Comment: Have you tried to *not* link with the library? Does the macOS manual pages for the functions you use say you must have the library? Or is it some other tutorial for another systems that tells you to use it?

Comment: From the message it should be clear it is not gcc.

Comment: I tried using simple gcc without -lnsl option but it certainly doesn't work. The command is made to work on Linux systems, and I thought it could work on mac os too. I just need to find a workaround or sth.

Comment: Please don't just say "it doesn't work". Noone can help you based on that information. Copy paste the error messages instead, so people can know what is actually going on.

Comment: Sorry. Without using -lnsl option, the program gives no errors, it runs, but the  socket functions don't work. For example, when I'm trying to send a message from client to server, nothing happens.

Comment: Then that is because of *another* problem, probably something in your code that you need to debug to find out (and if you need help with it you should post another question about it, containing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Please read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first. Note that the `nsl` library (or the lack of it) is *not* what causes your other problem.

Comment: Then the issue is with your code, which you have not shown. Even though your code works fine on linux, does not mean it is 100% bug free, or needs some adjusting or porting when you want to run it on OSX. Please post your code and everything else that you deem relevant, if you want people to help you.

Comment: It is not a problem in my code. I tried running the  same code on Linux with -lnsl option and it works perfectly.

Comment: Why do you think adding -lnsl or any other library will fix your bug?

Comment: Since the error says library not found for -lnsl??

Comment: Who has told you that a program which runs on Linux has no bugs and must also run on Mac OS X with no modification? Or on a different Linux?

Comment: Mac OS X has no libnsl. Functions that live in libnsl on Linux are found in the standard C library on Mac OS X.

Comment: Noone, I just spoke from my experience with mac os. So far most of the code that ran on Linux, also worked on mac os. I'm just trying to find a workaround here. Socket programming is pretty important. I assume there is sth I can do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OS X has no libnsl. Functions that live in libnsl on Linux are found in the standard C library on Mac OS X. No additional flags are necessary for building programs that use these functions.

If your program works on Linux and doesn't work on a Mac, then your program has a bug that is triggered on Mac OS X but not on Linux. No amout of fiddling with linker flags is likely to change that.

Comment: Oh, damn. My bad. I modified some things in the code and now it seems to work without any flag. Thanks.